# pick specific checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have some checkboxs with the same name but each has a unique value.
I want that on any click on specific checkbox to get the unique value of the cpecific clicked checkbox.

```
@foreach (var itert in Model.collec)
            {

                            @Html.CheckBox("chkResend",
                            new { @value = Html.Encode(itert.EventNumber), 
@class = "myclass" })

 };
```

the jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(".myclass").click(function () {
        alert($(".myclass").attr("value"));
    });

});
```

all the time I get the value of the first checkbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".myclass").click(function () {
        alert(this.value); //this refers to the current element clicked
        // or alert($(this).attr("value"));
        // or alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```